# How do I change the value of a cell based on the position of a team in a table?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not the best at Excel and vba however I do know some of the basics. I am looking to create a spreadsheet for a forum prediction game. The game involves posters predicting the league table before the season and seeing how close they were with every place that the team was out a point would be added to their score.

The example of this would be that I have predicted Exeter to finish 7th. If say they finish 4th then I will get 3 points. If they finish 17th I will get 10 points.

The way I was thinking of having the spreadsheet work is by having everyones predictions alongside the real league table in which the spreadsheet would compare one cell of say Exeter in the 4th position cell to the real table where Exeter sit in 7th. The spreadsheet would then output this as 3 points to the certain players score in a different sheet.

The only problem is that I don't know how I would go about creating this and what functions or vba would be needed to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
=SUM(ABS(MATCH(B2:B11,$B$2:$B$11,0)-MATCH(B2:B11,$A$2:$A$11,0)))
```

It's an array formula, so enter it using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

[image]